# fsolve gives an error "TypeError: can't convert complex to float

Tags: python

I am trying to run fsolve on the following function:

```
   func = lambda D1: float(PH_qp1-phase(csqrt(omega*1j/D1)* \
  special.kv(1,csqrt(omega*1j/D1)*ri)/special.kv(0,csqrt(omega*1j/D1)*ri)) \
    /2/pi)
```

When I run the function itself, it returns a real number, but if I try to run `fsolve`:

```
D_init = 0.1
D_sol = fsolve(func, D_init)
```

it gives me the error

```
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

Comment: Can you show all imported packages?

Comment: import numpy as np
from cmath import sqrt as csqrt, phase, pi
from scipy import special
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

Comment: @Sklert import numpy as np from cmath  \                                                            
import sqrt as csqrt, phase, pi    \                                                               
from scipy import special   \                                                                        
from scipy.optimize import fsolve \

Answer (score 0):

`func` should be

> [scipy.optimize.fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)
>   Parameters: 
>       func : callable f(x, *args)
>       A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument.

Comment: The function works on its own, has one variable D1, and returns a real value.  fsolve works on a simple problem like finding the square root of 2.  It seems like fsolve can't access the cmath functions when it calls the function   to be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

I used newton_krylov instead of fsolve. It works great as long as my initial guess is less than the true value.